# Printing strings and concept of null character in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, initialization, c-strings

While reading about printing strings, I came through a statement **"`printf` writes the character one by one untill it encounters a null character. If the null character is missing, `printf` continues past the end of the string until-eventually-it finds a null character in the memory".** So I wrote some codes:

**Case 1:**

```
char arr[4] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' } ;

if (arr[3]== '\0')

printf ("%s",arr);
```

Output was `abc`.

So does it mean compiler has automatically stored `'\0'` at `arr[3]`. Because according to the statement, printf will only terminate when it encounters `'\0'`.

**Case 2:**

```
char arr[3] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' } ;

if (arr[3]== '\0')

printf ("%s",arr);
```

Output was `abc` again though there is no array block  `arr[3]` in existence, so why isn't that an error? Also printf has printed `abc` and stopped which means it must have encountered `'\0'`. So does that mean compiler creates an extra array block after `arr[2]` to store `'\0'`.If so then array size must be increased to 4 bytes (1 byte for each char type character). But executing the statement `printf ("%d",sizeof (arr));` gives me output `3`, showing that there is no increase in array size and indicating that there is no `arr[3]`. Then how does the condition `if (arr[3]== '\0')` became true?

**Case 3:**

```
char arr[3] = "abc";

if (arr[3]== '\0')

printf ("%s",arr);
```

Now it gives me an error saying that *"array index 3 is past the end (which contains 3 elements)".* So why isn't this same with **case 2**. Does that mean that declarations:

`char arr[3] = "abc";` and

`char arr[3] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' } ;` are different.

Comment: "*[...] so why isn't that an error?*" It is an error. It's just that C doesn't require the compiler or runtime system to *detect* the error. Anything can happen.

Comment: So can answers be different with different compilers?

Comment: They can even be different with different versions of the same compiler, or different compilation options, or just from running the same program multiple times. There are no guarantees and no expectation of consistency.

Comment: I get it now. Looks like I have been overthinking on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the size of an array is larger than the number of elements you explicitly initialize, then the remaining elements will be zero-initialized.

So you can have e.g.

```c
char arr[50] = { 'a' };
```

The first element (`arr[0]`) will be initialized to contain `'a'`, the remaining 49 elements will all be zero.

Also note that when you define an array of three elements (like in the second two examples in your question) and then use `arr[3]== '\0'` you are indexing out of bounds and have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Furthermore, the contents of memory not inside your array is *indeterminate*. You can't rely on it being any value.

And lastly,

```
char arr[3] = "abc";
```

and

```
char arr[3] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
```

are actually the same, both create an array of three elements with the contents `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'`.

Comment: @Avi The character `'\0'` is the octal value `0` in character form. It's exactly equal to `0`. It's also exactly equal to `'\x00'`.

Comment: @Avi Why not? `0` and `'\0'` are exactly the same.

Comment: Sorry I got that. They both are same

Comment: But how in case 2 that condition *(a [3]=='\0`)* true bcoz there is no a [3] present.

Comment: @Avi Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: @Avi C have never had any kind of bounds-checking. Going out of bounds leads to undefined behavior. Just don't do it.